# only single image presented in a row when using jQuery mobile grid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

1. I need the two images in a row, but I am only getting one per row.
2. Can anyone help me how to set the image captions?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_r/305ruk7f/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="grid-row" class="ui-grid-a">
  <a href="goTohomePage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'>
    <img src="img/new_application.png" height="100px" width="50px"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="grid-row"> 
  <a href="goToInprogressPage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'>
    <img src="img/new_application.png" height="100px" width="50px"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="grid-row" class="ui-grid-a">
  <a href="goTocompletedPage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'>
    <img src="img/new_application.png" height="100px" width="50px"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="grid-row">
  <a href="#" id="other-color" onClick='#'>
    <img src="img/new_application.png" height="100px" width="50px"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.grid-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-row img {
  max-width: 25% !important;
  width: 25% !important;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Mobile GRID classes to do this (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/grids/)

```
<div class="ui-grid-a grid-container">
    <div class="ui-block-a grid-row">
         <a href="goTohomePage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/1/" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b grid-row">
         <a href="goTohomePage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/2/" /></a>
    </div>    
    <div class="ui-block-a grid-row">
         <a href="goTohomePage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/3/" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b grid-row">
         <a href="goTohomePage()" id="other-color" onClick='#'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/4/" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ui-grid-a class has 2 columns. Column 1 divs have the class ui-block-a, column 2 has ui-block-b.  Then to resize the images nicely, set your CSS to

```
.grid-row img{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/305ruk7f/7/)**

Comment: I need the same. But I need to add caption for the image. Any name for each image. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use float. Try by changing your CSS like below

```
.grid-row img
{

    max-width: 45% !important;
    width: 45% !important;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Still getting one image per one row

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for me?

Comment: Did you use width: 45% ?

Comment: yes I have used it still I am getting same result but image width gets increased

Comment: Change padding 30px to 10px or less!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to float and size the divs, then make the image fit inside it...

```
        .grid-container 
        {
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
         }

        .grid-row img
        {
            max-width: 25%;
            width: 25%;
            padding: 30px;
            floaT: left;
        }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/305ruk7f/2/)

Note that if you stretch the visible window width, the image will stretch. This is because you're fixing the height in html (and width too but css is overriding that).

Remove the widths/heights entirely:

```
<div class="grid-row"
     class="ui-grid-a">
         <a href="goTohomePage()" 
            id="other-color" 
            onClick='#'>
               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/3/"/>
         </a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/305ruk7f/5/)

A couple of other code-cleanup things...

- Assign multiple classes in one parameter: `...class="grid-row ui-grid-a"...`